# Finding the most available employees with a django query

Tags: django

I have 2 tables/models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Shift(models.Model):
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="shift_set")
```

I need a list of all employees who can work a shift at during a specified date range.  I'd like this list sorted by availability (most available at the top).  I have this query which partially works:

```
qs = Employee.objects.filter(shift_set__start_at__gte=start_at,
                             shift_set__end_at__lte=end_at
                             ).annotate(overlapping_events=models.Count('shift_set'))
return qs.order_by('overlapping_events', 'last_name', 'first_name')
```

The problem with this query is I only get the people who have conflicts, not those that don't.  Employees who have no shifts scheduled don't show up in this list, even though they should be at the top of the list.  How do I also include employees that have no shifts in this date range?

So I modified it slightly like so:

```
qs = Employee.objects.filter(
    Q(shift_set__isnull=True)
    | Q(shift_set__start_at__gte=start_at, shift_set__end_at__lte=end_at)).annotate(
        overlapping_events=models.Count('shift_set__employee__id'))
return qs.order_by('overlapping_events', 'last_name', 'first_name')
```

But out of 100 Employees, 20 still get left out, these are the 20 that have shifts, but have no conflicts.

How do I write this query in Django?

Answer (score 0):

if the first (unmodified) query returns qs = (unwanted/conflicting objects), couldn't you then run Employee.objects.all() and simply exclude gs (ordering the remaining objects as desired?)